# How do I check an objects property types?

Tags: php, object

Sorry for the title, I couldn't find a better way to write it =/

I am receiving a error object called ErrorBase.

If there is only one error it will return me the following:

```
public 'ErrorBase' => 
      public 'CODIGO_ERRO' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'MENSAGEM_ERRO' => string 'Autenticação Inválida' (length=24)
      public 'TIPO_ERRO' => string 'Usuario' (length=7)
```

But if there is more than one error, it will return me a array of objects like this:

```
public 'ErrorBase' => 
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'CODIGO_ERRO' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'MENSAGEM_ERRO' => string 'Autenticação Inválida' (length=24)
      public 'TIPO_ERRO' => string 'Usuario' (length=7)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'CODIGO_ERRO' => string '002' (length=3)
      public 'MENSAGEM_ERRO' => string 'teste 002' (length=9)
      public 'TIPO_ERRO' => string 'tipo 002' (length=8)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'CODIGO_ERRO' => string '003' (length=3)
      public 'MENSAGEM_ERRO' => string 'teste 003' (length=9)
      public 'TIPO_ERRO' => string 'tipo 003' (length=8)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'CODIGO_ERRO' => string '004' (length=3)
      public 'MENSAGEM_ERRO' => string 'teste 004' (length=9)
      public 'TIPO_ERRO' => string 'tipo 004' (length=8)
```

How can I work with these situations?
How do I check if there is a array of objects or only a object?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is ErrorBase ? Your pseudo-code is not very clear.

Comment: is just a class...this is a var_dump() of the returned class

Comment: so the class `ErrorBase` also has a property called `ErrorBase` ? in that case `if(is_array($instanceOfErrorBase->ErrorBase)) { /* stuff */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is_array()` :

```
if (is_array($this->ERROR_BASE))
```

Comment: it won't work because its a class, it will always return me a object with arrays inside it

Comment: I have checked for the type on both results and both returns me a object, no t a array.

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
is_object() and is_array()
```

Comment: Both ways will return me a object, as it is, I need to check the property type, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

`is_array($variable)` returns true if `$variable` contains an array, and false otherwise.

Comment: it won't work because I'll always have a object as return and this object have a array inside, I need to check if what is inside this object is a array of objects

Answer (score 0):

To test the class of an object :

```
if ($var instanceof ErrorBase) {
```

To test if it is an array :

```
if (is_array($var)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

use `gettype()` to returns the vars type.

or use `is_array`/`is_object` to test for each

Comment: it will return a object always...I need to check what is inside that object...not what the object is...